# How do I disable a button within a mat-selection-list <mat-list-option> if the mat-list-option is not selected?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a list of mat-list-options and I have a delete button for each of those options. I want to disable the delete button in the content of the mat-list-option if the mat-list-option is not itself selected. Here is what I have been trying:

```
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let query of userQueries" [contextMenu]="savedQueryOptions" [contextMenuSubject]="query" class="user-queries" id="currentQuery">
            <div>
              <span> {{query.queryName}}
                <button mat-icon-button ng-disabled="!currentQuery.selected">
                  <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
```

How do I find out if the parent with the id of "currentQuery" is selected? Or maybe there is a better way to get ng-disabled to get the correct value??

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-selection-list #savedQueries>
          <mat-list-option #thisQuery *ngFor="let query of userQueries" class="user-queries" [value]="query.queryId">
            <div>
              <span> {{query.queryName}}
                <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="!thisQuery.selected" matTooltip="Delete selected query">
                  <mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon>
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
```